# VS 2012 project conversion troubles

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, c++-cli

I have a VS 2010 solution with a delicious mix of C++/CLI and C# projects.
I decided to move on to VS 2012 for further development. Due to some technical difficulties the C++/CLI projects cannot be upgraded. This has created some problems for me. I have nightly build scripts that compile the said solution using the **devenv** command. All the C++/CLI projects fail to compile.

The IDE, when triggered, promptly asks for converting all projects. I say NO and compile and all works well.

My investigation:

I tried the following approaches to understand what actually is happening. The MSBUILD log verbosity was also increased. In all the cases VS 2012 command prompt was used.

**Case 1:**

msbuild {C++/CLI project name} /t:rebuild

**Result:**

The project compiles fine and uses the VS 2010 compiler. The following line from the log shows that:

> Creating "x64\Debug\Swift.Algorithms.unsuccessfulbuild" because
>   "AlwaysCreate" was specified. ClCompile:   C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\bin\x86_amd64\CL.exe

**Case 2:**

devenv {C++/CLI project name} /rebuild "{CONFIGURATION}"

**Result:**

The project compiles fine and uses the VS 2010 compiler. The following line from the log shows that:

> 1>Using "CL" task from assembly "Microsoft.Build.CppTasks.x64,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a".
>   1>Task "CL" 1>  Environment Variables passed to tool: 1>
>   VS_UNICODE_OUTPUT=1512 1>  **C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio 10.0\VC\bin\x86_amd64\CL.exe**

**Case 3: (The one that frustrates me)**

devenv {Solution File Name} /rebuild "{CONFIGURATION}"

The C++/CLI projects fail to compile. C# projects compile fine. The C++ compiler being used in this case is the VS 2012 version. The following line from the log shows that:

> 1>  Environment Variables passed to tool: 1>    VS_UNICODE_OUTPUT=1016
>   1>  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   11.0\VC\BIN\x86_amd64\CL.exe /c

**Questions:**

1) I see that MSBUILD is clever enough to use the proper tools when the project file is individually being used for compilation. It really does not matter what VS tools command prompt (VS 2010 or VS 2012) is used. What is going wrong when the solution file is called?

2) I see the only way to compile my product is to compile each project individually as the Solution file is causing trouble. Is this a known limitation?

I would appreciate any input on this matter.

Comment: Is there any compelling reason for using `devenv` over `msbuild`? And do you have the platform tools set correctly? i.e. the VS2010 ones http://blogs.msdn.com/cfs-filesystemfile.ashx/__key/communityserver-blogs-components-weblogfiles/00-00-00-65-69/7725.xptarget.png

Comment: I have seen some issues in the earlier days where build order for our product was different when I used devenv in place of msbuild. msbuild would make the compilation fail. Did not investigate much after that as devenv worked fine.

Comment: If memory serves me, that might be because VS2005 didn't actually have MSBuild-based projects (????) and MSBuild would make temporary projects from the non-MSBuild ones. http://weblogs.asp.net/kdente/archive/2005/06/05/410432.aspx I imagine that would be a complex process to get right. So if you're on VS2008+ maybe it's time to give MSBuild another try?

Comment: I assume that, despite not explicitly saying so, that you have the platform toolset set to VS2010 on your C++/CLI projects?

Comment: I want it to point to VS 2010 toolset. It is doing so when I use msbuild and devenv to compile the project alone. But when I use devenv for compiling the solution file, the VS 2012 toolset is being used although I did not convert the C++/CLI projects to 2012 version.

Comment: Yes but the link in my first comment, the C++/CLI project's platform toolset is set to VS2010, yes? Unless I am missing something.

Comment: True. I feel I should simply update all C++/CLI projects to 2012 version and then change the toolset version to 2010. This should be the solution. But why is the Case 3 a failure scenario? Someone from Microsoft need to answer that. 
Could you turn your comment into an answer so that I may accept it?

Comment: Done, although I feel it's not really worthy of "answer" status because it does not sound like I am solving your problem.

Comment: OK. I too felt the same. But let your comment be an answer. I will accept it(or NOT) based on whether others provide anything more useful. It is better to wait for more.

Answer (score 0):

Whether you're building with `msbuild` or `devenv` (and I personally would prefer `msbuild`) I would imagine that, at a minimum, the `Platform Toolset` of each Visual C++ project should be set to `Visual Studio 2010`.

[image: Platform Toolset]